# Can't extract a large zip file

Tags: files, zip, unzip

System says my zip file is okay, but I can't extract it through `unzip`. I think maybe because it's such a large file (34 GB) that `unzip` might not support it.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: What error's do you get ?

Comment: What's the complete command used  ? If you used a GUI could you try with unzip command ?

Comment: i tried the command line unzip.
i get the following:
file #66350:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  38631718912
and
file #65841:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  35508700841

Comment: it seems that unzip is not ready for such a large file

Comment: i tried also 7z (the command line tools), but it didn't work either with no error.

Comment: @hamidi or the `zip` file is corrupt or incomplete!

Comment: yes, or, but how can i make sure? at first step, i prefer to accept the integrity of the zip file. because during making it, he didn't get any error.

Comment: Use the `shasum` from the source if avalable or  or `zip -T existing.zip`

Comment: what is it? calculates shasum for a file, like md5 or something? how can it help?

Comment: Did you run `zip -T name_of_zip_file.zip`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66145/discussion-between-hamidi-and-george).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just extracted a 13GB file.  I was unable to unzip it using the extract tool, right clicking on the file (I'm in KDE, so this is dolphin).  I ran into a similar error, where it said that "The archive you're trying to open is corrupt. Some of the files may be missing or damaged.".  Instead I used dtrx from the command line, and it worked on the first try.

To install dtrx I typed: `sudo apt-get install dtrx`

To run the extraction I typed `dtrx filename.zip` with no flags.

Answer (score 4):

Using the java archiver (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025742/unzipping-large-file-bad-zipfile-offset-local-header-sig)) did the trick for me. The syntax is as follows:

```
jar xvf file.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your file download is incomplete. From [here](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/99/) it says:

> For reference purposes, with the Zip64 extension to the Zip file format enhancement, Zip files of 16 exabytes, which is over 16 billion gigabytes (or 2 to the 64th power bytes) are possible. Likewise, over 4 billion files and folders can be included in a Zip file.

Please check the integrity of your `zip` file with: `zip -T name_of_zip_file.zip`, an `OK` is expected if download was complete. And current Ubuntu 64bit has `zip64` capability already compiled into your `zip tool`. Check that with `zip -v`

Comment: Zip64 is a format or a tool?

Comment: I believe you have `64bit Ubuntu` so `zip64` version should be in use

Comment: yes i do. but how can i make sure?

Comment: Run `zip --version` and check for it in the output

Comment: Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.

Comment: zip64 command not found

Comment: @George: The Zip64 format and `zip`’s capability to decompress and extract it don't depend on the CPU word length. Zip64 archives work just fine on 32-bit operating systems.

Comment: @DavidFoerster ok noted

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)

If it is not already installed, install the p7zip-full package:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then do:

```
7z x file.zip
```

You can also use it with `.7z` and (with `p7zip-rar`) `.rar` files.

Answer (score 0):

say, did you try all the other unpackers
which are available ?
there is also p7zip, b1 Archiver (snap store)
and more..

i have had couple of zips rars and so forth sometime,
which did not or did not correctly unpack, 
in case this happens i simply switch to use
another unzipper/unpacker for the file.

(it sometimes helps)