# Unzipping large file: bad zipfile offset (local header sig)

Tags: unzip

I am unzipping a file with approximately 3 million single text files - the zip-file itself is around 12 GB in size. It's not multi-part - it's just one large zip file btw. I do not have the original data - all I have is the zipped file which means I cannot try to zip the content again (just so you know).

The problem is that as I `unzip`, at some point, I get

```
..
file #1207565:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570252890
file #1207566:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570254437
file #1207567:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570255044
file #1207568:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570256141
file #1207569:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570256786
file #1207570:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570257539
..
```

This does not seem to affect every subfolder or file respectively in the archive but for a lot of them the process seems to fail.

At this point it's hard for me to guess if the packing or the unpacking is the problem

Are there any workarounds I could try on my side?

Comment: Suggestion online and via man pages is to use: `zip -F original.zip --out fixed.zip` and then try to extract fixed.zip as normal...

Comment: @andrew.46 On it - although I had to "*try harder*" using `-FF` in order to make it run at all - what I can see though are warning and things like "*skipping this signature ..*" - I guess that means those files are not going to make it into `fixed.zip`?

Comment: @andrew.46 Okay, I tried it twice - unfortunately this does not work. It ends up with the same error messages. :/

Comment: NB: macOS can create these problem zips - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518097/2732969 .

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same problem - a huge zip file with a lot of files - and unzip choked trying to unpack it. A possible solution is to use java archiver. Just unpack your stuff with `jar xvf file.zip`

Comment: This is sadly the working solution for me too

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to copy the comment into an answer, although I had to use the "try harder" `-FF` option to get it to work:

> Suggestion online and via man pages is to use: `zip -F original.zip --out fixed.zip` and then try to extract `fixed.zip` as normal...